# Need a mod_rewrite .htaccess solution to replace %20 spaces with -'s in the finished URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cgi-bin

I need an .htaccess mod_rewrite solution that will take a .cgi search query like this:

www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/finda/therapist.cgi?Therapy_Type=Pilates Training&City=Los Angeles&State=CA

and return matching results in the browser's address bar to look like this:

- `www.mydomain.com/therapists/Pilates-Training-Los-Angeles-CA.html`

or better yet:

- `www.mydomain.com/therapists/pilates-training-los-angeles-ca.html`

Notice the database includes values with one, two or three words + spaces...

For example:

```
Therapy_Type=Pilates Training <- includes a space

City=Los Angeles <- includes a space

State=CA <- no space
```

I used the tool at: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ to generate the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /cgi-bin/finda/therapist.cgi?Therapy_Types=$1&City=$2&State=$3 [L]
```

This does work (finds the search matches) and generates the results page, but because the parameter values have spaces in them, we end up with a URL that looks like this:

www.mydomain.com/therapists/Pilates%20Training-Los%20Angeles-CA.html

I've spent days in this forum and others trying to find a solution to get rid of these %20 (encoded spaces) so the final returned URL will look like 1) or 2) above.

I know someone on here must know how to do this... Help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the %20 with -, then how would you know where the therapy type ends and the city starts?

```
pilates-training-los-angeles-ca
```

would be

```
type=pilates
city=training
state=los
```

So I don't think you like to replace the %20 by -. You could however replace it with another character, like _:

```
pilates_training-los_angeles-ca
```

You then would have to translate every _ to a space within your PHP script (or whatever language you are using server side).

Comment: OK, that's a good point... If I follow you, that means I can use a _ character to separate the search parameters; Or I could use a '/' as in a new URL like this:

 - /pilates-training/los-angeles/ca.html

-'s = spaces

/'s = separate field names (type, city, state)

Now as to the **translation** part you mentioned; e.g. converting the _'s or in my example -'s into real spaces to fetch the script's search results...

The search script is a .cgi (.pl) that I created years ago using the self-serve script creator called FLATTEXT over at: flattext.com (now unsupported).

Comment: I understand I have to pass the variable values pilates-training & los-angeles (stripped of the -'s) as: pilates training & los angeles

I don't know how or where to modify the .cgi script to substitute in the spaces (where applicable) to get the search result, then reinsert the -'s for the finished URL.

Isn't it possible to do this (replace -'s with spaces; then replace spaces back to -'s) inside a modified RewriteRule?

Comment: For instance, using the example URL: pilates-training/los-angeles/ca.html

To extract;

> Therapy_Type=pilates training

> City=los angeles

> State=ca

from the above URL, which is run through the .cgi script?

I do have control of the .cgi script but I was thinking a mod_rewrite solution would be better than messing inside the script.

To state the obvious, I don't pretend to understand the complexities of regex or .pl

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No I don't see how you could do this in a RewriteRule alone, since you would need a rewrite within the rewrite.