# mod_rewrite .htaccess with %20 translate to -

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have been reading about .htaccess files for a couple of hours now and I think I'm starting to get the idea but I still need some help. I found [various](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39494/how-to-rewrite-20-in-htaccess) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689528/how-to-redirect-20-or-white-space-automatically-to-or-with-htaccess) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407594/need-a-mod-rewrite-htaccess-solution-to-replace-20-spaces-with-s-in-the-fini) SO but still unsure how to do this.

As far as I understand you write a rule for each page extension you want to 'prettify', so if you have `something.php` , `anotherpage.php`, `thispage.php` etc and they are expecting(will receive??) arguments, each needs its own rule. Is this correct?

The site I want to change has urls like this,

```
maindomain.com/sue.php?r=word1%20word2
```

and at least one page with two arguments

```
maindomain.com/kevin.php?r=place%20name&c=person%20name
```

So what I would like to make is

```
maindomain.com/sue/word1-word2/
maindomain.com/kevin/place-name/person-name/
```

Keeping this .php page and making it look like the directory. Most of the tutorials I have read deal with how to remove the .php page to which the argument is passed. But I want to keep it.

the problem I am forseeing is that all of the `.php?r=`parts of the url are the same ie `sue.php?r=`, `kevin.php?r=` and the .htaccess decides which URL to change based on the filename and then omits it. If I want to keep the file name will I have to change the `?r=`
so that it is individual? I hope this make sense. So far I have this, but I'm sure it won't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$1.php?r=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$1.php?r=$1&c=$1
```

And I think I have to add `([^-]*)` this in some part or some way so that it detects the `%20` part of the URL, but then how do I convert it to `-`. Also, how are my `$_GET` functions going to work??

I hope my question makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space somewhere in those rules, but I think you've got the right idea in making 2 separate rules. The harder problem is converting all the `-` to spaces. Let's start with the conversion to GET variables:

```
# check that the "sue.php" actually exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?r=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?r=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Those will take a URI that looks like `/sue/blah/` and:

1. Extract the `sue` part
2. Check that `/document_root/sue.php` actually exists
3. rewrite `/sue/blah/` to `/sue.php?r=blah`

Same thing applies to 2 word URI's

Something like `/kevin/foo/bar/`:

1. Extract the `kevin` part
2. Check that `/document_root/kevin.php` actually exists
   3 rewrite `/kevin/foo/bar/` to `/kevin.php?r=foo&c=bar`

Now, to get rid of the "-" and change them to spaces:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(c|r)=([^&]+)-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2=%3\ %4 [L]
```

This looks a little messy but the condition matches the query string, looks for a `c=` or `r=` in the query string, matches against a `-` in the value of a `c=` or `r=`, then rewrites the query string to replace the `-` with a  (note that the space gets encoded as a `%20`). This will remove all the `-` instances in the values of the GET parameters `c` and `r` and replace them with a space.

Comment: This is so complex. Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I'm going to see if I can get this to work on MAMP first

Comment: This is not working on my tester server, MAMP neither no idea why. Would it be that the files are in a sub directory? Options in not allowed on the server.

Comment: @AdamBrown If your actual URL's look like `http://domain/some-dir/sue/word1/word2`, then yeah, that `/some-dir` will break everything. The answer was based on the assumption that everything's in the document root, like it is written in your question.

Comment: Thats just the testing server. I'll have to risk it. Thanks once again